# Assign random missing values

Tags: r

I have a data set with missing values in it, I was able impute the missing values using different methods. Now I want to estimate the accuracy of the imputation methods. But since I don’t know what is the true values before imputation, I am thinking to mask some values in the original data “data with missing values”, then use my regular imputation methods. After finishing the imputation I can compare the imputed values with the true values to estimate the imputation accuracy.
So, my question is: say I want to assign 100 elements in the data set to be NA, how to pick 100 elements that is not missing to assign NA to it. Then, how to track these element for further analysis?

Example

```
library(BLR)
library(missForest)
data(wheat)
X2<- prodNA(X, 0.1) ## original “ data with 10 % missing values 
X3<- missForest(X2)$Ximp ## imputed data set
```

Comment: have a look at `?sample`

Answer (score 3):

#### This method will ensure exactly N points are pulled, with no duplicates

```
## Assuming 'DF' is your data.frame or data.table

# The number of values to set to NA
N <- 10
inds <- as.matrix(expand.grid(1:nrow(DF), 1:ncol(DF)))

# Drop any indecies where DF is NA
inds <- matrix(inds[!is.na(DF[inds])], ncol=2)

# Sample randomly
selected <- inds[sample(nrow(inds), N), ]

# Note that `selected` is a matrix of (row, col) indices
DF[selected] <- NA
```

Comment: Ricardo:  thank you for your answer --- However, my DF already has NA in it ---- my question is how to select only 10 elements that is not NA in DF --- also i think your are selecting 10 rows to be NA, we just want to select 10 elements to be NA.

Comment: @hema, see the edit for not-selecting elements which are already NAs in DF.   As for the point of selecting rows: notice that `selected` is a matrix, not a vector.  Hence, when used inside `[ ]`, it is selecting individual elements, not entire rows.